# owl carousel: flickering on tablet view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

We are implementing **owl carousel**  It is fine on desktop view on all resolutions, but flickering complete page which contains that owl carousel on tablet view (ipad).

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-center" id='answersheet_status'></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="text-center" id='assessment_feedback'>
                            <!--<a href="#" class="pull-right close-btn-assessment" id="close_btn_assessment"><i class="fa fa-times">y</i></a>-->
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="main_div_section">
                    <div class="col-md-12 question-section">
                        <div id="section_div" class="col-md-12 owl-carousel owl-theme" style="padding:0 20px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="alernate_div_section hide" id="alernate_div_section"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 no-padding mt15">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="section-result"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12  no-padding mt15" id="questions_div">                           
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="question-footer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Js code:**

```
var carousel = $('.owl-carousel');
    carousel.owlCarousel({
                    rtl: false,
                    margin: 10,
                    nav: true,
                    loop: false,
                    mergeFit: true,
                    startPosition: start_pos,
                    responsive: {
                        0: {
                            items: 1
                        },
                        600: {
                            items: 3
                        },
                        1000: {
                            items: 3
                        },
                        1200: {
                            items: 4
                        },
                        1400: {
                            items: 5
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Note: If we remove that owl carousel, then the page works fine at all. **We don't want that flickering** on ipad (tabletview), why this happens? any solution? please suggest.

*(owl carousel Version used : version 2.0.0)*

Comment: Please be sure to read the tag descriptions.  This has nothing to do with [tag:OWL], the Web Ontology Language.  It usually helps to add language tags (e.g., [tag:javascript]) and primary library tags (e.g., [tag:jquery]).  I've edited the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;  // added this
}
```

Please add the above code in your css file , and see that the class are define in html code ...

This works fine with me ....